# Execute multiple queries using a single JDBC Statement object

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

In JDBC, can I use single `Statement` object to call `executeQuery("")` multiple times? Is it safe? Or should I close the statement object after each query, and create new object for executing another query.

E.G:

```
Connection con;
Statement s;
ResultSet rs;
ResultSet rs2;
try
{
    con = getConnection();
    // Initially I was creating the Statement object in an
    // incorrect way. It was just intended to be a pseudocode.
    // But too many answerers misinterpretted it wrongly. Sorry 
    // for that. I corrected the question now. Following is the 
    // wrong way, commented out now. 
    // s = con.prepareStatement();
    
    // Following is the way which is correct and fits for my question.
    s = con.createStatement();

    try
    {
        rs = s.executeQuery(".......................");

        // process the result set rs
    }
    finally
    {
        close(rs);
    }

    // I know what to do to rs here
    // But I am asking, should I close the Statement s here? Or can I use it again for the next query?

    try
    {
        rs2 = s.executeQuery(".......................");

        // process the result set rs2
    }
    finally
    {
        close(rs2);
    }
}
finally
{
    close(s);
    close(con);
}
```

Comment: This thread may be informative: http://www.java-forums.org/jdbc/69824-proper-use-preparedstatment.html

Comment: Re-using the `Statement` instance is definitely possible even recommended for performance reasons.

Comment: That link is dead. I only mention it because it says ```Database error
The database has encountered a problem``` which is pretty ironic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure why you are asking. The API design and documentation show it is perfectly fine (and even intended) to reuse a `Statement` object for multiple `execute`, `executeUpdate` and `executeQuery` calls. If it wouldn't be allowed that would be explicitly documented in the Java doc (and likely the API would be different).

Furthermore the apidoc of [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says:

> All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's [*sic*] current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.

This is an indication that you can use it multiple times.

TL;DR: Yes, you can call `execute` on single `Statement` object multiple times, as long as you realize that any previously opened `ResultSet` will be closed.

Your example incorrectly uses `PreparedStatement`, and you cannot (or: should not) be able to call any of the [`execute...` methods accepting a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) on a `PreparedStatement`:

> `SQLException` - if [...] the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`

But to answer for `PreparedStatement` as well: the whole purpose of a `PreparedStatement` is to precompile a statement with parameter placeholders and reuse it for multiple executions with different parameter values.

Comment: Great, thanks for detailed explanation of what I asked and what I missed. I just revisited this after years, and I am tempted to mark it as accepted answer, even if the other one has more votes. Because this one also answers the confusion behind the question in first place.

Comment: And also this answer sheds light on wrong part of question, corrects it, and answers both correct and wrong versions of question. Thanks again. Would want to upvote it 10 times.

Answer (score 29):

Yes you can re-use a `Statement`(specifically a `PreparedStatement`) and should do so in general with JDBC. It would be inefficient & bad style if you didn't re-use your statement and immediately created another identical `Statement` object. As far as closing it, it would be appropriate to close it in a finally block, just as you are in this snippet.

For an example of what you're asking check out this link: [jOOq Docs](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/reusing-statements/#N129B1)

Comment: What about reusing a ResultSet? Is that a good practice too? On the code provided above, the person created two ResultSet objects

Comment: @Erick Yes reusing a `ResultSet` is ok as well as long as you're properly closing it after you're done with it. You can reuse a single `ResultSet` and `Statement` as long as the operations are done in serial, not parallel. ie  instantiate run query 1 with your `Statement`, get back value xyz from the `ResultSet`; close the statement, instantiate & run query 2 with your `Statement` using value xyz

Comment: What about `Statement`s that aren't `PreparedStatement`s?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find anything in the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) that would state, that you shouldn't call `executeQuery()` on a given `PreparedStatement` instance more than once.

However your code does not close the `PreparedStatement` - a call to `executeQuery()` would throw a `SQLException` in that case - but the `ResultSet` that is returned by `executeQuery()`. A ResultSet is [automatically closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29), when you reexecute a `PreparedStatement`. Depending on your circumstances you should close it, when you don't need it anymore. I would close it, because i think it's bad style not to do so.

***UPDATE*** Upps, I missed your comment between the two try blocks. If you close your PreparedStatement at this point, you shouldn't be able to call executeQuery() again without getting a SQLException.

Comment: Your comment in the middle asks if you should close it there. But anyways, yes it is safe to reuse it.

Answer (score 4):

A `Prepared Statement` tells the database to remember your query and to be prepared to accept parameterized variables to execute in that query. It's a lot like a stored procedure.

`Prepared Statement` accomplishes two main things:

1. It automatically escapes your query variables to help guard against SQL Injection.
2. It tells the database to remember the query and be ready to take variables.

Number 2 is important because it means the database only has to interpret your query once, and then it has the procedure ready to go. So it improves performance.

You should not close a prepared statement and/or the database connection in between execute calls. Doing so is incredibly in-efficient and it will cause more overhead than using a plain old `Statement` since you instruct the database each time to create a procedure and remember it. Even if the database is configured for "hot spots" and remembers your query anyways even if you close the `PreparedStatement`, you still incur network overhead as well as small processing time.

In short, keep the `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` open until you are done with them.

Edit: To comment on not returning a `ResultSet` from the execution, this is fine. `executeQuery` will return the `ResultSet` for whatever query just executed.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how so? OP asked if it's OK to reuse `PreparedStatement`, and I've explained it is ok, and why.

Comment: After re-reading the question and your answer, it might be me who is confused. The OP creates a `PreparedStatement` (in an invalid way), but uses it as a normal `Statement` object by using the execute methods that accept a query string (which isn't allowed, see my answer). I initially read the question to be about `Statement`, and in that case your answer doesn't answer it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ya, the OP has a lot wrong in the snippet. Since `PreparedStatement` is really a best practice in probably round-a-bouts 95% of the time, then I chose to address that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I am confused about your code

```
s = con.prepareStatement();
```

Is it work well?I can't find such function in JAVA API,at least one parameter is needed.Maybe you want to invoke this function

```
s = con.createStatement();
```

I just ran my code to access DB2 for twice with one single Statement instance without close it between two operation.It's work well.I think you can try it yourself too.

```
    String sql = "";
    String sql2 = "";
    String driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:db2://ip:port/DBNAME";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    int count = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Result row count of query number one is: " + count);
    count = 0;
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Result row count of query number two is: " + count);
```

Comment: I recon for the ease of reading he used this non working kind of pseudo code. `close(rs)` should also be `rs.close()` and you would need a `null` check in finally and another `try`/`catch` etc.