# Using a ResultSet after executing two different queries with statement.executeQuery()

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Given the code below:

```
    //connection stuff
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query1);

    statement.executeQuery(query2);

    while(rs.next){
       //code
    }
```

Is the result set `rs` still valid even though a second statement has been executed?

I know that when you close a statement the result set isn't valid any longer, but here the code is simply executing another query and not storing it in a result set.

Comment: It has already been answered, have a look here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327012/execute-multiple-queries-using-a-single-jdbc-statement-object][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327012/execute-multiple-queries-using-a-single-jdbc-statement-object

Comment: There are ways to operate with result sets with identical result columns produced by different queries.  For example, you can use SQL set operations on the two queries prior to forming the result set.  There are other alternatives.  You need to tell us more about the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Marco_MontaltoM That is a different question and involves sequential use of a statement, this question is about interleaved use of a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `statement` is a `Statement`, from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

The posted code is unsafe - the second call to `executeQuery` will return a new `ResultSet`, and given only one can be open at a time `rs` will not be valid.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was very unsure when I came across that question, but it makes perfect sense. So even though the second ResultSet isn't put into a ResultSet object the first ResultSet doesn't exist anymore, and will throw a runtime exception when rs.next() is called.